# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have problem with PMA on my server. The PMA folder is loaded into disk space (by WinSCP) and I cannot access from the web browser. What have I to do?

I have seen topics with similiar problem, but I didn't find answer for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the phpMyAdmin files in your web root and load it through your browser. If the folder on disk is `/var/www/phpmyadmin` then load `http://example.com/phpmyadmin`.

The phpMyAdmin manual also has a [quick install guide](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install).